# ActionScripts3 POST to URL issue

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to use API of SMSPVA.com, when i copy and paste URL to Firefox it return json values, but in Actionscripts3 wrong value appear in output. 
I thing my code is not right.

I want to POST data over URL and print response with "trace" in output window.

```
import flash.net.*;

 function URLRequest_method() 
{
    var url:String = "http://smspva.com/priemnik.php?metod=get_balance&service=opt4&apikey=HPQjg2cyfY2KhkyAjJft";

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    urlLoader.load(request);

    trace(request.data);

}
```

Edit:

```
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.Event;

 function URLRequest_method():void
{
    var url:String = "http://smspva.com/priemnik.php?metod=get_balance&service=opt4&apikey=HPQjg2cyfY2KhkyAjJf";

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);    
    urlLoader.load(request);

}


 function onLoaderComplete(event:Event):void
{
    var urlLoader2:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader ;
    trace(urlLoader2.data);
    trace(event.target.data.done);
}


URLRequest_method();
```

Result is true: "{"response":"1","balance":"0.00"}"

but a warning show too: "ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property done not found on String and there is no default value."

What thing is wrong?

Comment: Uhm, Are you sure you want to tell us your apikey?

Comment: yes this is test user id, i never use it for any purpose except test APIs.

Comment: Ah I see. Concerning your issue, have you tried using GET instead? You say that you copy paste the url into firefox, do you mean the url bar or did you write a test site for that purpose? Because iirc the browser URL is a GET request by default.

Comment: Copy paste in firefox. I'm new to actionscripts3.

Comment: Change `URLRequestMethod.POST` to `URLRequestMethod.GET` and check the result.

Comment: It returns same output as POST. "[object URLRequest]"

Comment: i know "trace(request);" is not true but i don't have any idea for replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urlLoader.load(request);` is async operation, you should listen for `Event.COMPLETE` event to get the loaded data:

UPD:

```
    function URLRequest_method():void
    {
        var url:String = "http://smspva.com/priemnik.php";
        var postParams:URLVariables = new URLVariables("metod=get_balance&service=opt4&apikey=HPQjg2cyfY2KhkyAjJf");

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        request.data = postParams;

        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
        urlLoader.load(request);

    }

    function onLoaderComplete( event:Event ):void
    {
        var urlLoader2:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;
        trace( urlLoader2.data );

        var json:Object = JSON.parse( urlLoader2.data );
        trace( "json.response = ", json.response );
        trace( "json.balance = ", json.balance );
    }
```

Output:

```
{"response":"1","balance":"0.00"}

json.response =  1
json.balance =  0.00
```

Btw, your endpoint does not support `POST` method, only `GET`

Comment: Thanks, Now please check new codes and tell me where is problem, if you can please write complete code.

Comment: But why my output window is empty? no data no warning nothing. I created new ActionScripts3 document in Animate CC for your new code.